# Can't edit anything inside a jqGrid form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jqgrid

I really thought I had a grasp on jqGrid considering I have a ton of inline editing grids throughout my application. However, it seems that I'm not nearly as versed on enabling and editing with a jqGrid form rather than inline. If anyone can spot a blatant mistake in my jqGrid configuration, please let me know. Code is as follows:
**JS**

```
$(function() {
    var lastDate,
        issueOpts = {1:'Incorrect Material Shipped', 2:'Incorrect Material Ordered', 3:'Defective Material', 4:'Incorrect Quantity', 5:'Incorrect Pricing', 6:'Incorrect Ship To'},
        dtcOpts = ['0', '15', '30', '60', '90', '120'],
        ownerOpts = {15619:'Candi Allen', 101102:'Carla King', 100476:'Victoria Townsend', 101101:'Tanya Watson'},
        $vmiGrid = $('#vmiGrid'),
        $vmiFoot = $('#vmiFoot'),
        vmiEditParam = {
            keys:true,
        },
        formProps = {
            topinfo:'Vendor Management Editor',
            closeAfterEdit: true,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            modal: true,
            navkeys: true,
            width: 450
        },
        vmiAddParam = {
            rowID:'new',
            position:'last',
            addRowParams: vmiEditParam
        },
        navParms = {
            add:false,
            edit:true,
            del:false
        };
    function calcVMIForm() {
        var creditMaterials, creditRestock, creditFreight, creditInstall, creditOther, creditTotal;
        creditMaterials = parseFloat( $('#rma_material_cost').val(), 10 );
        creditRestock = parseFloat( $('#rma_restock').val(), 10 );
        creditFreight = parseFloat( $('#rma_freight').val(), 10 );
        creditInstall = parseFloat( $('#rma_install_credit').val(), 10 );
        creditOther = parseFloat( $('#rma_other_credit').val(), 10 );
        creditTotal = creditMaterials - creditRestock + creditFreight + creditInstall + creditOther;
        $('#rma_expected_credit').val(creditTotal);
    }
    function changeRMADue() {
        var cb_date = new Date();
        var requested_date = $('#rma_requested').datepicker('getDate');
        var days_to_clear = $('option:selected', this).text();
        var d = requested_date.getDate();
        var m = requested_date.getMonth();
        var y = requested_date.getFullYear();
        cb_date = new Date(y, m, d + parseInt(days_to_clear, 10));
        $('#rma_clear').datepicker('setDate', cb_date);
    }
    $('#special_dialog').dialog({
        width:'auto',
        height:'auto',
        resizable:true
    });
    $.extend($.jgrid.defaults,{
        gridview:true,
        loadui:'block',
        rowNum:500,
        rowList:[20,50,100,500],
        viewrecords:true,
        sortorder:'asc',
        height:500,
        autowidth:true,
        deepempty:true,
        altRows: true,
        grouping: true,
        groupingView: {
            groupField: ["vendor"],
            groupColumnShow: [true],
            groupText: ["<b>VENDOR: {0}</b>"],
            groupDataSorted: true,
            groupSummary: [false]
        }
    });

    //////////////////////////////
    // setup VMIs grid
    //////////////////////////////
    $vmiGrid.jqGrid({
        url: '/json/json.getVMIsGrid.php',
        datatype:'json',
        emptyrecords: 'No Open VMIs',
        colNames: [
            '',
            'VID',
            'Vendor',
            'Job Number',
            'VMI Number',
            'Owner',
            'Requested',
            'Due',
            'DTC',
            'PO Number',
            'Materials',
            'Re-Stock Fee',
            'Freight Cost',
            'Install Hours',
            'Issue',
            'Install Credit',
            'Other Credit',
            'Expected Credit',
            'Credit Number',
            'Credit Received',
            'Notes'
        ],
        colModel: [
            {   name:'id',
                index:'r.id',
                hidden:true,
                key:false,
                search:false,
                viewable:false
            },
            {   name:'vendor_id',
                index:'r.rma_vendor',
                width:0,
                hidden:true,
                search:false,
                align:'center',
                viewable:true,
                editable:true,
                edittype:'text',
                editoptions:{size:8,readonly:true}
            },
            {   name:'vendor',
                index:'vendor',
                width:100,
                sortable:true,
                sorttype:'text',
                align:'left',
                editable:true,
                classes:'ui-ellipsis',
                edittype:'text',
                editoptions:{size:50,readonly:true},
                editrules:{required:true}
            },
            {   name:'order_number',
                index:'j.order_number',
                width:100,
                sortable:true,
                editable:false,
                classes:'ui-ellipsis',
                align:'center'
            },
            {   name:'vmi_number',
                index:'r.vmi_number',
                width:90,
                sortable:false,
                editable:false,
                align:'center'
            },
            {   name:'rma_owner',
                index:'r.rma_owner',
                width:100,
                sortable:false,
                editable:true,
                edittype:'select',
                align:'right',
                editoptions:{value:ownerOpts,readonly:true}
            },
            {   name:'rma_requested',
                index:'r.rma_requested',
                width:85,
                sortable:true,
                sorttype:'date',
                editable:true,
                align:'center',
                edittype:'text',
                editoptions:{   size:15,
                                dataInit: function(l) {
                                    $(l).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
                                }
                            },
                editrules:{required:true}
            },
            {   name:'rma_clear',
                index:'r.rma_clear',
                width:85,
                sortable:true,
                sorttype:'date',
                editable:true,
                align:'center',
                editrules:{required:true},
                editoptions:{   size:15,
                                dataInit: function(l) {
                                    $(l).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
                                }
                            }
            },
            {   name:'rma_dtc',
                index:'r.rma_dtc',
                width:55,
                sortable:false,
                editable:true,
                align:'center',
                classes:'dtc',
                edittype:'select',
                editrules:{required:true},
                editoptions:{
                    value:dtcOpts,
                    dataEvents: [
                        {
                            type:'change',
                            fn: changeRMADue
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {   name:'rma_po_number',
                index:'r.rma_po_number',
                width:60,
                sortable:true,
                editable:true,
                edittype:'text',
                editoptions:{size:30},
                align:'center'
            },
            {   name:'rma_material_cost',
                index:'r.rma_material_cost',
                width:60,
                sortable:true,
                editable:true,
                edittype:'text',
                editoptions:{
                        size: 15,
                        maxlength: 8,
                        dataEvents: [
                            {
                                type: 'change',
                                fn: calcVMIForm
                            }
                        ]
                },
                editrules:{
                    number: true,
                    minValue: 0
                },
                formoptions: {label:'Material Cost $'},
                align:'center'
            },
            {   name:'rma_restock',
                index:'r.rma_restock',
                width:60,
                sortable:true,
                editable:true,
                edittype:'text',
                editoptions:{
                        size: 15,
                        maxlength: 8,
                        dataEvents: [
                            {
                                type: 'change',
                                fn: calcVMIForm
                            }
                        ]
                },
                editrules:{
                    number: true,
                    minValue: 0
                },
                formoptions: {label:'Re-stock Fee $'},
                align:'center'
            },
            {   name:'rma_freight',
                index:'r.rma_freight',
                width:60,
                sortable:true,
                editable:true,
                edittype:'text',
                editoptions:{
                        size: 15,
                        maxlength: 8,
                        dataEvents: [
                            {
                                type: 'change',
                                fn: calcVMIForm
                            }
                        ]
                },
                editrules:{
                    number: true,
                    minValue: 0
                },
                formoptions: {label:'Freight $'},
                align:'center'
            },
            {   name:'rma_install_hours',
                index:'r.rma_install_hours',
                width:60,
                sortable:true,
                editable:true,
                edittype:'text',
                editoptions:{size:30},
                align:'center'
            },
            {   name:'rma_issue',
                index:'r.rma_issue',
                width:160,
                sortable:false,
                editable:true,
                edittype:'select',
                editoptions:{value:issueOpts},
                align:'right'
            },
            {   name:'rma_install_credit',
                index:'r.rma_install_credit',
                width:60,
                sortable:true,
                editable:true,
                edittype:'text',
                editoptions:{
                        size: 15,
                        maxlength: 8,
                        dataEvents: [
                            {
                                type: 'change',
                                fn: calcVMIForm
                            }
                        ]
                },
                editrules:{
                    number: true,
                    minValue: 0
                },
                formoptions: {label:'Install Credit $'},
                align:'center'
            },
            {   name:'rma_other_credit',
                index:'r.rma_other_credit',
                width:60,
                sortable:true,
                editable:true,
                edittype:'text',
                editoptions:{
                        size: 15,
                        maxlength: 8,
                        dataEvents: [
                            {
                                type: 'change',
                                fn: calcVMIForm
                            }
                        ]
                },
                editrules:{
                    number: true,
                    minValue: 0
                },
                formoptions: {label:'Other Credit $'},
                align:'center'
            },
            {   name:'rma_expected_credit',
                index:'r.rma_expected_credit',
                width:60,
                sortable:true,
                editable:true,
                edittype:'text',
                formoptions: {label:'Expected Credit $'},
                align:'center'
            },
            {   name:'rma_credit_number',
                index:'r.rma_credit_number',
                width:90,
                sortable:true,
                editable:true,
                edittype:'text',
                editoptions:{size:50},
                align:'center'
            },
            {   name:'rma_credit_received',
                index:'r.rma_credit_received',
                width:60,
                sortable:true,
                editable:true,
                edittype:'text',
                formoptions: {label:'Credit Received $'},
                align:'center'
            },
            {   name:'rma_notes',
                index:'r.rma_notes',
                width:250,
                sortable:false,
                editable:true,
                edittype:'textarea',
                classes:'ui-ellipsis',
                editoptions:{rows:'3',cols:'55'}
            }
        ],
        pager:'#vmiFoot',
        sortname:'r.id',
        caption:'All Open Vendor Management Issues',
        onSelectRow: function(id) {
            var $self = $(this);
            $self.jqGrid('editGridRow', id, formProps);
        },
        editurl:'/jqg/jqg.saveVMIEdit.php'
    });
    $vmiGrid.jqGrid('navGrid','#vmiFoot',navParms);
    $('#special_dialog').dialog({
        resizeStop: function(e,ui) {
            $vmiGrid.jqGrid('setGridWidth', ui.size.width - 20);
        },
        buttons:{
            "Done!" : function() {
                $('#special_dialog').dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="vmiGrid"></table><div id="vmiFoot"></div>
```

[image: the grid]
[image: the form]
[image: This is the console view of the Materials Cost input field]

Comment: Could you explain more clear *what you want* to implement? You current code contains a mix between inline editing (see `vmiEditParam`, `vmiAddParam` for) and form editing. *How* you want to start editing? You use `onSelectRow` with `formProps` options and `navGrid` without the options. Your code contains some syntax problems like `creditRestock + + creditFreight` or usage of `creditTotal` without corresponding definition by `var`. **What exactly problem you have currently?** You don't posted any pictures, any test data or any working demo. Can you reproduce the problem with 1-2 columns?

Comment: @Oleg I ONLY want to edit via form, no inline editing allowed. I have removed the `creditRestock ++ creditFreight` syntax error and added a declaration for `creditTotal`. Currently, the `edit form` opens just fine but does not allow any of the `text` inputs to be changed. I will update with photos.

Comment: Are you sure that you included jQuery UI CSS? What you mean that the text can't be changed? Do you mean that that all `<input>` fields are disabled/readonly or you **can't save** the modified data on the server?

Comment: @Oleg Yes, jQuery UI CSS is included. All the `text` input fields and the single `textarea` field act as if they are `readonly`. The `select` boxes allow changes.

Comment: @Oleg I don't think that's case, since I can change the `select` inputs. Also, I have viewed the form elements in the `console` and they do not have `readonly` or `disabled` attributes.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use? Could you temporary comment all columns of grids in `colModel` and `colNames` with exception one editable input and one input. If the problem still exist and you can't localize it then you can prepare small demo with 2 columns and some rows of data (probably 1 row will be already enough), which reproduce the problem. The demo should use non-minimized version of jqGrid (I mean `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`). Then I could debug the demo and to find the reason of the problem. Probably you will find the reason yourself during preparing it

Comment: By the way you can see only *the attributes* of the `<input>` element and not it's *properties*. By the way `readonly:true` is wrong inside of `editoptions`. It should define *attribute* `readonly` which value should be the string `"readonly"`. The boolean *property* `readonly` which is not part of HTML fragment can be set to `true`.

Comment: jqGrid 4.6.0 (minified). I will attempt to comment out all but a couple of lines but I still believe it's in the configuration of the `formEdit` and that there might be some `inlineEdit` options messing it up.

Comment: @Oleg Now, THIS is very odd! If I go into the console and change the `input type` to `number`, I can edit the fields via the `up/down` arrows but the value still remains unselectable and the field itself cannot be typed in. Is there a `role` or `aria` missing according to my console image?

Comment: All attributes are OK, but you can execute `$("#rma_material_cost").prop("readonly", true)` in the console to make input readonly without changing attribute. Probably some strange CSS which will applied do this. I recommend you to comment different parts of your code (like I described above) and CSS included on the page. I'm sure that in the way you will find the reason.